# Outputting to two worksheets

Tags: vba, excel

I have the below function that outputs records to either a worksheet called CI or one called Error. I added an additional IF statement where if my source 'col' column contains the word "TITER" then I want it to output to the "Error" worksheet. This seems to be working and outputting the appropriate records to the Error tab. **However** I noticed that it is also outputting these same records to the "CI" worksheet as well. I have the IF code nested in the main Else statement, but I'm thinking it doesn't belong there. Any help is appreciated!

```
Public lstrow As Long, strDate As Variant, stredate As Variant
Sub importbuild()
lstrow = Worksheets("Data").Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Function DateOnlyLoad(col As String, col2 As String, colcode As String)
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
    j = Worksheets("CI").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    k = Worksheets("Error").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

    For i = 2 To lstrow
        strDate = spacedate(Worksheets("Data").Range(col & i).Value)
        stredate = spacedate(Worksheets("Data").Range(col2 & i).Value)

        If (Len(strDate) = 0 And (col2 = "NA" Or Len(stredate) = 0)) Or InStr(1, UCase(Worksheets("Data").Range(col & i).Value), "EXP") > 0 Then
            GoTo EmptyRange
        Else
            If InStr(1, UCase(Worksheets("Data").Range(col & i).Value), "TITER") > 0 Then
                Worksheets("Error").Range("A" & k & ":C" & k).Value = Worksheets("Data").Range("F" & i & ":H" & i).Value
                Worksheets("Error").Range("D" & k).Value = "REVIEW MMR1 DATES"
                k = k + 1
            End If
            Worksheets("CI").Range("A" & j & ":C" & j).Value = Worksheets("Data").Range("F" & i & ":H" & i).Value
            Worksheets("CI").Range("D" & j).Value = colcode
            Worksheets("CI").Range("E" & j).Value = datecleanup(strDate)
            Worksheets("CI").Range("L" & j).Value = dateclean(strDate)
            Worksheets("CI").Range("M" & j).Value = strDate
            If col2 <> "NA" Then
                If IsEmpty(stredate) = False Then
                    Worksheets("CI").Range("F" & j).Value = datecleanup(stredate)
                End If
            End If
            j = j + 1
        End If
EmptyRange:
    Next i
End Function
```

Comment: I've edited your post format, you will be able to see why it is writing it on both sheets. And yes, the Else statement is applying to a different potion of the code and not the "TITER" Statement. It is strong recommended to apply spaces/tab whenever you open an If/For/Do/With segment to easily spot the code that belongs inside that segment.

Comment: Also try to avoid use of `Goto` except for error handling or when absolutely needed (which is rare)

Comment: @RicardoA What did you change in the code? It appears the same to me.

Comment: @nick He fixed the indentation.

Comment: I'm unclear as where to change the code. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I only added indentation (Spaces) to make it easy to read. I have posted a quick answer with a an edit to make sure that it only writes on the Error sheet if it finds "TITER".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please review and compare to original code. You can see the quick change made. Indentation helps so much to spot errors and/or opportunities to improve the code.

```
Function DateOnlyLoad(col As String, col2 As String, colcode As String)
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
    j = Worksheets("CI").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    k = Worksheets("Error").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

    For i = 2 To lstrow
        strDate = spacedate(Worksheets("Data").Range(col & i).Value)
        stredate = spacedate(Worksheets("Data").Range(col2 & i).Value)

        If (Len(strDate) = 0 And (col2 = "NA" Or Len(stredate) = 0)) Or InStr(1, UCase(Worksheets("Data").Range(col & i).Value), "EXP") > 0 Then
            GoTo EmptyRange
        Else
            If InStr(1, UCase(Worksheets("Data").Range(col & i).Value), "TITER") > 0 Then
                Worksheets("Error").Range("A" & k & ":C" & k).Value = Worksheets("Data").Range("F" & i & ":H" & i).Value
                Worksheets("Error").Range("D" & k).Value = "REVIEW MMR1 DATES"
                k = k + 1
            Else
                Worksheets("CI").Range("A" & j & ":C" & j).Value = Worksheets("Data").Range("F" & i & ":H" & i).Value
                Worksheets("CI").Range("D" & j).Value = colcode
                Worksheets("CI").Range("E" & j).Value = datecleanup(strDate)
                Worksheets("CI").Range("L" & j).Value = dateclean(strDate)
                Worksheets("CI").Range("M" & j).Value = strDate
                If col2 <> "NA" Then
                    If IsEmpty(stredate) = False Then
                        Worksheets("CI").Range("F" & j).Value = datecleanup(stredate)
                    End If
                End If
                j = j + 1
            End If
        End If
EmptyRange:
    Next i
End Function
```

Comment: I think that the block starting with `If col2` and ending with `j = j + 1` should also belong within `Else`, but it's only my best guess.

Comment: @Recardo A When I changed the code to your suggestion then I am loosing all of the records that should have qualified for the Else condition for the "CI" worksheet.

Comment: @RicardoA thanks! It fixed this issue. Now I have discovered another issue with other text in the date field, but will probably open a seperate thread.